# How do I implement an animation of a picture hiding on top?

Tags: android, image, android-animation

[image]

How to hide image on top using material animations?
I can rotate image or change "X" "Y" but how can I do this task?

Comment: You can use `View.animate().translationY(value)`

Comment: Is code only change position Y. I need hide image on top.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to used clip. For example this file name is clipper.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<clip xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:clipOrientation="vertical"
    android:drawable="@drawable/dog"
    android:gravity="bottom" />
```

Your image layout would contain this ImageView

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:src="@drawable/clipper"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

And in you fragment you can use this snippet:

```
val animator = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(0, 10000)
        animator.apply {
            interpolator = LinearInterpolator()
            duration = 1000
        }
        animator.addUpdateListener {
            val animProgress = it.animatedValue as Int
            binding.imageView.drawable.level = 10000 - animProgress
        }
        animator.start()
```